# isAuthorized redirect URL cakephp

Tags: cakephp, authentication

When `isAuthorized = false` the user is redirected to '/' is there a way to change this. I want to redirect to the user dashboard (/users/dashboard) with a flash message saying 'Access prohibited' or something like that.

Cheers!

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
        return true; //Admin can access every action
    }
    return false; // The rest don't
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your isAuthorised variable is being evaluated in your controller.

You can call the redirect function.

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
```

If you are actually inside the users controller allready, just call

```
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'dashboard'));
```

If not, where are you checking the isAuthorised value?

This is not an ideal solution. However it seems that there is no way to do this with the current built in AuthComponent

Edit: Added code as an example.

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
if (parent::isAuthorized($user)) {
    return true;
}
// Authorised actions
if (in_array($this->action, array('dashboard'))) {
    return true;
}
// Will break out on this call
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm using the cakephp method AuthComponent::isAuthorized.

Comment: isAuthorised is just a boolean check.
If the answer is false, call the redirects I listed above.

Comment: isAuthorized returns a boolean. However this is then used within the cakecore to perfore the redirect. I simply set true/false. I've updated with code to show my example.

Comment: Is the function you amended inside of your AppController?

Comment: the docs say:  If all checks fail, the user will be redirected to the page they came from. But it doesnt seem to work correctly. The above function is in appcontroller. Then I have a similar function in my UserController    `public function isAuthorized($user) {
        if (parent::isAuthorized($user)) {
            return true;
        }`

Comment: This question intrigued me, so I've dug around a little and come to the following conclusions.

The packaged AuthComponent doesn't offer you a way to set a custom redirect target for a failed isAuthorised() call.

But you can still call a redirect within the isAuthorised function. The function will stop executing, but it will still do the redirect.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. After looking in the core at AuthComponent.php:335 `$controller->redirect($controller->referer('/'), null, true);` it shows that they redirect to the referrer. The problem here was that referer was not being set, so it was using the default '/'. I can hard code the value into the core. Or set `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] = "/users/dashboard";` in my isAuthorized method.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use exception and extends like that :

AppController.php

```
 public function isAuthorized($user) {
    throw new ForbiddenException(__('You are not authorized to access.'));
 }
```

AnotherController.php

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
        return true;
    }
    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

With this code you are able to manage the roles and the error.

Answer (score 0):

If they are being logged out you can send them where you want with:

```
$this->Auth->logoutRedirect
```

I would personally use:

```
$this->Auth->authError = "You are not authorized to access.";
```

In order to redirect them to root with a flash message notifying them of the error.

Comment: Can I prevent them from being logged out? I only want to restrict access (only for a few views so ACL is overkill).

Comment: on what basis are you restricting them?

Comment: If the user role is admin they can access an export view. If the role is not not admin, when they try and access the export view they should be redirected to the dashboard. I was hoping to contain this within isAuthorized so I can easily add new pages when needed. In order to view the dashboard the user must be logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Is a wrong behavior of AuthComponent.
In a nutshell: if the url is visited by a link, the framework is able to reconstruct the path and then redirect to the referring page. Otherwise (by direct entry into a url bar) it fails and it redirects to the home page.
 
The "bug" is documented and it will be corrected in a future release.

See: http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/591-inconsistent-redirect-behaviour-by-auth-acl

Answer (score 0):

I do a little better than @deep55.

isAuthorized() method can throw an exception no problem, but i think that the inheritance of the Controllers would permit us to improve authorization algorithm using first AppController.isAuthorized(), not last.

So, here is my solution, assuming that I use a user model called Utilisateur, and a role model called Role.

AppController :

```
/**
 * Parent method
 */
    public function isAuthorized($user){
        App::uses('Utilisateur','Model');
        $User = new Utilisateur();
        $isAdmin = $User->hasRole(10,$user['id']);
        if ($isAdmin) {
            return true;                
        }

    }
/**
 * Reject unauthorized actions
 */
    public function rejectRequest(){
        $errorMessage = __("Sorry, you can't do this.");
        if ($this->isRest()) {
            throw new ForbiddenException($errorMessage);
        } else {
            $this->Auth->authError = $errorMessage;
            $this->Auth->flash['params']['class'] = 'alert-danger';                
        }
        return false ;
    }
```

Utilisateur model :

```
/**
 * hasRole method return true if the user belongs to the correct role group
 */
    public function hasRole($role_id, $user_id){
        if (!isset($user_id)) {
            if (!empty($this->id)) {
                $user_id = $this->id ;
            } else throw new Exception("Error, parameter $user_id is missing", 1);              
        }
        $user = $this->find('first',array(
            'conditions' => array('Utilisateur.id' => $user_id),
            'fields' => array('id'),
            'contain' => array('Role.id')
        ));
        $roles = $user['Role'];
        foreach ($roles as $r) {
            if ($role_id == $r['id']) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

And last, in a specific controller :

```
/**
 * Child method
 */
public function isAuthorized($user){
    if (parent::isAuthorized($user)) {
        return true;
    }

    if ( false ) {
        return true ;
    }
    if ( false ) {
        return true ;
    }

    return $this->rejectRequest() ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Cake version 2, as written in [documentation for AuthComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html):

> **AuthComponent::$unauthorizedRedirect**
>
> Controls handling of unauthorized access. By default unauthorized user is redirected to the referrer URL or AuthComponent::$loginRedirect or ‘/’. If set to false a ForbiddenException exception is thrown instead of redirecting.

you can configure AuthComponent to redirect you to custom page in one place using `unauthorizedRedirect` property.
Just set it in the place where you configure Auth as a component

```
'Auth' => array(

     ... other settings...,

    'unauthorizedRedirect' => '/users/dashboard'
)
```

After being redirected, you can print error message defined by `authError` property

```
echo $this->Session->flash();
echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
```

but it will be the same message for any authentication or authorization error.